# Return a sublist based on member variable or mapping function

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, guava

I have a list of pojo's  `List<Pojo> pojoList`;  and `pojo.getColour();` returns an Enum instance.

And I want to do this :

```
List<Pojo> newlist = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
for(Pojo pojo:pojoList){
  if(pojo.getColour() == Colour.Red){
    newList.add(pojo);
  }
}
```

I could see myself using a similar function for lists of other types so rather than repeating a lot of code is their a way to make it generic and/or functional ? So that I could create sublists of different types based upon a different rule ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I should note that if you just want a new `ArrayList` containing the matching elements, the way you did it in your example is just fine. Until Java has lambda expressions, you're not going to get it simpler or better looking than that.

Since you tagged this with [guava](/questions/tagged/guava), here's how you *could* do this with Guava. You're basically filtering the original list on the composition of a predicate (`== Color.Red`) and a function (`pojo.getColour()`). So if you had a static final `Function<Pojo, Colour>` called `COLOUR` on `Pojo` (like this):

```
public static final Function<Pojo, Colour> COLOUR =
    new Function<Pojo, Colour>() {
      @Override public Colour apply(Pojo input) {
        return input.getColour();
      }
    };
```

you could create that combination like this:

```
Predicate<Pojo> isRedPojo = Predicates.compose(
    Predicates.equalTo(Colour.Red), Pojo.COLOUR);
```

You can then create a filtered view of the original list:

```
Iterable<Pojo> redPojos = Iterables.filter(pojoList, isRedPojo);
```

And you could copy that filtered view into an `ArrayList` if you want:

```
List<Pojo> copy = Lists.newArrayList(redPojos);
```

Comment: apache commons-collections also has good utilities for this.  Collection<Pojo> filtered = CollectionUtils.filter(pojoCollection, new Predicate() { ... });

Comment: @Matt: I think the commons-collections filter method _removes_ elements that don't match from the original collection, which I don't really like. Guava has the more explicitly named `Iterables.removeIf(Iterable, Predicate)` method for doing that.

Comment: could you specify what the `Function` looks like?

Comment: @hakunami: The body of the `apply` method would just look something like `return input.getColour();`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make your type implement a common interface for the check:

```
public interface Candidate {
  public boolean isAddable();
}
```

The loop then would look like this

```
List<Candidate> newlist = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
for(Candidate pojo:pojoList){
 if(pojo.isAddable()){
   newList.add(pojo);
 }
}
```

and the `Pojo` class would have to implement the interface:

```
public class Pojo implments Candidate {

  // ...

  @Override
  public boolean isAddable() {
    return isRed();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that requiring the `Candidate` implementation to define exactly one criteria for selecting elements (the `isAddable()` implementation) is too limiting. A predicate/matcher based approach allows any number of different ways to filter elements.

Answer (score 1):

make an generic filter interface

```
public interface Filter<T>{
     public boolean match(T item);
}
```

make a method using the filter

```
public <T> List<T> getFilteredList(List<T> oldList, List<T> filter){
   List<T> newlist = new ArrayList<T>();

   for(T item:oldList){
      if(filter.match(item)){
         newlist.add(item);
      }
   }

   return newlist;
}
```

put it all together

```
List<Pojo> myList = .. 

List<Pojo> redList = getFilteredList(myList,new Filter<Pojo>(){
      public boolean match(Pojo item){ return item.isRed()};
});

List<Pojo> blueList = getFilteredList(myList,new Filter<Pojo>(){
      public boolean match(Pojo item){ return item.COLOR== Color.BLUE};
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often you use it / how many different filters (only red, only green etc.) you are using, it could make sense to create a Filter interface - if it is only to check isRed then it is probably too much code and you are better off with a simple static method.

The good thing about this design is you can use it with any objects that you want to filter (see example with String below).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pojo> originalList = Arrays.asList(new Pojo(true), new Pojo(false), new Pojo(false));
    List<Pojo> filteredList = Utils.getFilteredList(originalList, new Filter<Pojo>() {
        @Override
        public boolean match(Pojo candidate) {
            return candidate.isRed();
        }
    });
    System.out.println(originalList.size()); //3
    System.out.println(filteredList.size()); //1

    //Now with strings
    List<String> originalStringList = Arrays.asList("abc", "abd", "def");
    List<String> filteredStringList = Utils.getFilteredList(originalStringList, new Filter<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean match(String candidate) {
            return candidate.contains("a");
        }
    });
    System.out.println(originalStringList.size()); //3
    System.out.println(filteredStringList.size()); //2
}

public static class Utils {
    public static <T> List<T> getFilteredList(List<T> list, Filter<T> filter) {
        List<T> selected = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T t : list) {
            if (filter.match(t)) {
                selected.add(t);
            }
        }
        return selected;
    }
}

public static class Pojo {
    private boolean isRed;

    public Pojo(boolean isRed) {
        this.isRed = isRed;
    }

    public boolean isRed() {
        return isRed;
    }
}

public interface Filter<T> {

    /**
    * When passed a candidate object, match returns true if it matches the filter conditions,
    * or false if it does not.
    * @param candidate the item checked against the filter
    * @return true if the item matches the filter criteria
    */
    boolean match(T candidate);
}
```